# "London is an easy place to get lost in." — What is the object of "in" here: "an easy place", "a place" or "place"?

Tags: parsing, objects, infinitive-clauses

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (pages 1248-1249), "hollow to-infinitivals licensed by an attributive adjective":

> [i] *London is an easy place to get lost in __*.
> [ii] *The price was a difficult one to better __*.

> These initial examples bear a clear resemblance to the construction just discussed: they are comparable to "*London is easy to get lost in*" and "*The price was difficult to better*". The applicability of the adjective is contingent on it being construed with the infinitival: [i] doesn’t say that London is an easy place, but that London is a place which it is easy to get lost in. Likewise in [ii] it is not a matter of a difficult price, but of a price that it would be difficult to better. It makes sense, therefore, to treat the infinitivals here as indirect complements in the structure of the NP: they are licensed not by the head of the construction, the noun, but by a dependent of it, the attributive adjective.

Did I understand correctly that:
In [i], the object of the preposition "*in*" is not the noun phrase "*an easy place*" but the noun phrase "*a place*".
In [ii], the object of the verb "*better*" is not the noun phrase "*a difficult one*" but the noun phrase "*one*".

---

an update:
It seems to me to consider the subjects ("London" in [i] and "the price" in [ii]) the objects of the non-finite clauses is incorrect because (according to nschneid's answer below) there is an analogous sentence where there is not such an opportunity:
**(3)** *Such an easy place to get lost in __ should have more signs*.
What is the object of "in" in (3)?

Comment: They both refer to the subject of the sentence: London and price. Related: [dangling preposition](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=dangling+preposition).

Comment: Per @WeatherVane, *It is easy to get lost **in London***.

Comment: ...and *It was difficult to better **the price***.

Comment: This is why some people will tell you to re-write sentences so you don't end them with a preposition. Compare: "London is an easy place in which to get lost."

Comment: If you understood those things, then you must have understood them from someplace else, because that passage says nothing about the object of "in" or of "better".

Comment: Oy, that explanation is horridly confusing. I'd rather see *lost in* as a verb phrase. Not lost out, lost for, but lost in.

Comment: I'd say that the object of "in" is "London". The object of "better" is the noun "price".

Comment: @BillJ What is the object of "in" in the sentence suggested in the answer below: "_Such an easy place to get lost in should have more signs_." Thanks.

Comment: An easy place to get lost in. because **to get lost in an easy place** /in an easy place/ is a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 3):

These are known to linguists as *tough*-constructions.

From

- London is an easy place to get lost in __.

we understand that it is easy to get lost in London. But structurally, contrary to the comments above, I think London cannot be the object. Consider:

- Such an easy place to get lost in __ should have more signs.

I think the object (antecedent of the gap) has to be a nominal phrase headed by "place". I don't know if it is completely explicit in CGEL whether that includes "an easy", but see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.17347.pdf p. 41 for one interpretation.